# Left Outer Join doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I got this piece of sql server 2005 code:

```
SELECT DT, a.id_uf, hora
FROM CALENDAR c LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT_MEDIDAS_COGEN a ON a.fecha_oferta = dt AND a.hora = c.H
WHERE 
(id_tipo_medida IN (6, 1)) AND (id_magnitud = 1) 
AND (DT BETWEEN '10/01/2013' AND '10/01/2013') AND (id_tipo_fact = 3)
ORDER BY DT, a.id_uf, a.hora
```

On calendar, I have got something like this:

[image: CALENDAR]

On CLIENT_MEDIDAS_COGEN I have got this:

[image: CLIENT_MEDIDAS_COGEN]

And finally, this is the result I am getting:

[image: Result]

The question is, how is it possible I'm not getting the rows for hours 1 and 2?? I'm using LEFT OUTER JOIN but it just doesn't seem to work properly.

Thank you so much in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of where filters which make it work like inner join. You can move where filters to join conditions, like this:

```
SELECT c.ID, a.id_uf, c.H
FROM CALENDAR c LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT_MEDIDAS_COGEN a ON a.fecha_oferta = dt AND a.hora = c.H
AND 
(a.id_tipo_medida IN (6, 1)) AND (a.id_magnitud = 1) AND (a.id_tipo_fact = 3)
WHERE (DT BETWEEN '10/01/2013' AND '10/01/2013') 
ORDER BY DT, a.id_uf, a.hora
```

That will make the desired left join effect.

Comment: You have moved the predicate on `dt` in to the `LEFT JOIN`.  This will mean that you always get the *whole* calendar table.  Instead, that one predicate should have remained in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @sarh Hi, thanks so much for your answer. I have tried and it doesn't give me the two missing rows. It is so weird, my query now is exactly as you suggest.

Comment: @rmartrenado that's strange - are you sure that they are not there, but in a wrong position? (for example in the end of resultsset) If so I think that's magic, I'd start to remove different parts of request to find out which statement cause this.

Comment: @sarh I'm playing with the query, will let you know as soon as I know what's going on. Thanks :D

Comment: @rmartrenado for example try to remove LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT_MEDIDAS_COGEN and all its fields, just to verify that a simple filter on CALENDAR brings those records

Comment: @sarh is is possible I have some SQL Server configuration that is not allowing the LEFT OUTER JOIN to work properly??? I checked that Calendar has the values for hours 1 and 2, for that date. I checked again that they are missing on Client_Medidas_Cogen, I tried removing fields from the ON clause and putting them on WHERE clause, and viceversa. Nothing works :(

Comment: @rmartrenado I beleive that values are there, but I was suggesting to check that they are returned with SELECT c.DT, c.H FROM CALENDAR c 
WHERE (DT BETWEEN '10/01/2013' AND '10/01/2013').
Also, a.Hora would not be populated for these two rows - we need c.H instead, I've updated the answer, you can check this one. I saw only one time the real bug with join, and I don't think that's the case. You can try to restore your db on some other SQL instance to check, or to prepare SQL fiddle model and play with it, to verify that it is not something wrong with your SQL instance.

Comment: @sarh I believe the problem is that id_uf is not part of CALENDAR, therefor the row dt= '2013-10-01' hora= 1 and hora=2 are being "delivered" together with other values of id_uf. I was expecting those rows to be delivered along with a NULL value for id_uf in that case. Maybe it is not going to happen while there is other id_uf for those two hours. I hope I made myself clear

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause states that `(id_magnitud = 1)`. Any rows in `Calender` that were not joined to `CLIENT_MEDIDAS_COGEN` will have `NULL` in the `id_magnitude` column.

```
SELECT 
    c.DT, 
    a.id_uf,
    c.hora
FROM 
    CALENDAR c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT_MEDIDAS_COGEN a ON a.fecha_oferta = dt AND a.hora = c.H
WHERE 
    (c.DT BETWEEN '10/01/2013' AND '10/01/2013') 
AND (COALESCE(a.id_tipo_medida, 1) IN (6, 1)) 
AND (COALESCE(a.id_magnitud, 1) = 1) 
AND (COALESCE(a.id_tipo_fact, 3) = 3)
ORDER BY 
    c.DT, a.id_uf, a.hora
```

Also don't just use the table alias for common columns. Use them for all columns so it's clear where the column resides.

As per MatBaille's comment moving the filters on `CLIENT_MEDIDAS_COGEN` to the join clause will perform better. The coalesce statments above just give an indication as to the reason for your issue. The below will likely perform better.

```
SELECT 
    c.DT, 
    a.id_uf,
    c.hora
FROM 
    CALENDAR c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT_MEDIDAS_COGEN a ON 
            a.fecha_oferta = dt 
            AND a.hora = c.H 
            AND (a.id_tipo_medida IN (6, 1)) 
            AND (a.id_magnitud = 1) 
            AND (a.id_tipo_fact = 3)
WHERE 
    (c.DT BETWEEN '10/01/2013' AND '10/01/2013') 
ORDER BY 
    c.DT, a.id_uf, a.hora
```

Comment: +1 : Instead of using `COALESCE` in the `WHERE` clause, I'd suggest simply moving those predicates to the `LEFT JOIN`.  This means that you won't need the `COALESCE` and as such will also allow use of indexes that cover those fields (should such indexes exist).

Comment: It doesn't retrieve the two missing rows. I totally understand your answer and you are right, but I am not able to find out why it doesn't get those rows. :(

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner (in my opinion) to use a subquery to apply the criteria to the right hand table in the join prior to the LEFT OUTER JOIN.

So it becomes...

```
SELECT c.ID, a.id_uf, c.H
FROM CALENDAR c 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECt id_uf, hora, fecha_oferta 
            FROM CLIENT_MEDIDAS_COGEN a 
            WHERE (id_tipo_medida IN (6, 1)) AND (id_magnitud = 1) AND (id_tipo_fact = 3)
        ) a ON a.fecha_oferta = dt AND a.hora = c.H

WHERE (DT BETWEEN '10/01/2013' AND '10/01/2013') 
ORDER BY DT, a.id_uf, a.hora
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. The two rows keep missing :(